# How to invoke certain JavaScript code only if Google Analytics scripts are enabled?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a form which invokes a JavaScript function on submit:

```
<form name="myForm" action="MyAction.html" method="get" onsubmit="return onSubmitForm();">
   ...
</form>
```

`onSubmitForm` should invoke Google Analytics and only if that *succeeds* return `false` to signal the browser that `MyAction.html` should not be executed at all. Unfortunately following snippet does not work as expected, as it seems to return `false` even when the user has disabled Google Analytics scripts in the browser:

```
function onSubmitForm() {
  return _gaq.push(['_link', linkUrl]);
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't know Google Analytics this good, but I think that you get your _gaq Variable from this, right? If so, then check if your variable is an object (typeof) and then return something.

Comment: What exactly should I try? I've tried some typeof's already without success.

Comment: I really don't know much about Google Analytics. But do you get a variable or object or a HTML tag if it is loaded? If so, then check if it exists...

Comment: Actually, that's my question: how exactly should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Standard asynchronous Google Analytics includes the snippet of code

```
var _gaq=_gaq||[]
```

which defines `_gaq` as an array. When `ga.js` gets loaded, `_gaq` get's replaced.

Try

```
_gaq instanceof Array
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `_gaq instanceof Array` is always false, regardless whether scripts are enabled or not.